# Can I file for B2 extension online?

Tags: usa, covid-19, b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions

I have to leave the US by January 13. I received a positive Covid test result today (January 9) so I won't be able to board the plane. I attempted to file an extension online with the USCIS website, but it is currently down. If it starts working again tomorrow and I am able to submit my application for a B2 extension online, will it be acceptable? How long does it usually take for the USCIS to acknowledge that they received my online application?

I know I should have done this 45 days before my stay ends, but now I'm in a rush to submit my application before January 13. I will try to call the USCIS tomorrow for clarification, but I am very worried that I won't have enough time to submit my application online.

Comment: As long as the "received date" is before or on Jan 13, you are fine. Online applications should be received quickly. You should have enough time if you file now.